# operator cannot be applied to java.lang.string java.lang.string

Tags: java

I keep getting this error, but believe I am trying to compare two strings...Am I missing something?

```
String classVolume = "SELECT class_id, COUNT(*) FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class GROUP BY class_id";
                if(classVolume >= rs.getString("class_size"){

                }
```

I tried to convert them both to Ints, but that didn't help.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are tryng to do, but this might help: `if(classVolume.cmpareTo( rs.getString("class_size")) >= 0`.

Comment: What do you expect the "value" of `classVolume` to be?  Are you expecting it to actually evaluate that database query?  Are you expecting the result to be an integer?  Or are you trying to look at the string as just text?

Comment: You don't have a column in your query aliased as "class_size".  You aren't executing the query.  You are attempting to compare the query string to (presumably) a result from the execution of the query.

Comment: Hi,  I have a class_size table in mysql that has a max capacity.  I want to say that if the class volume(which selects the count of students in the class) is greater than the max capacity, they can't enroll.

Comment: I have a column in my student_x_class titled class_size.  Does this have to be in the query as well?

Comment: If they are both strings, shouldn't I be able to compare them with >=?

Comment: why couldn't I convert them to Integer values and compare them with >=?

Comment: @J.Doe none of your code actually does an SQL query.  You're just writing down an SQL query and expecting it to get run.

Answer (score 1):

Use the compareTo method.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-

This will return an int which will be negative if the receiver is less than the argument.

```
if (classVolume.compareTo(rs.getString("class_size")) >= 0) ...
```